# Display post's description and caption

Tags: get-posts, post-meta, post-content

I am trying to get and display 5 featured posts. To achieve this target I have an offset of 5 recent posts. I have successfully fetched the posts' id's and images, but I failed to get every post's description.

I've tried the code below, but it only gives me 1 post description, not all 5 .

```
 $my_posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5,
   'offset'      => 5,
     'orderby'     => 'post_date',
       'order'       => 'DESC',
       'post_type'   => 'post',
         'post_status' => 'publish'));


 foreach($my_posts as $post) {

$data[] = 

array(
   "id" => $post->ID,
  "title" => $post->post_title,
  "image" => get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID),
 // "content" =>$post['post_excerpt'] 
  "content" => apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content)
);
                   }
```

Comment: What is a "post description"? Do you mean the excerpt? The content? Or are you talking about something added by a plugin or a custom post type with custom fields?

Comment: yes i  am talking about "excerpt" / "content"

Comment: Well, there is an automated excerpt which is extracted from the content and then there is the explicit excerpt, which has it's own meta box. And please file an [edit] for the info you are revealing. It does belong in the question, not in an comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you close (untested):

```
<?php
    foreach($my_posts as $post){
        $thisPostId = $post->ID;
        $thisPost = $get_post($thisPostId);
        $thisPostTitle = apply_filters('the_title', $thisPost->post_title);
        $thisPostThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($thisPost);
        $thisPostContent = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $thisPost->post_excerpt);

        $data[] = array(
            "id" => $thisPost,
            "title" => $thisPostTitle,
            "image" => $thisPostThumbnail,
            "content" => $thisPostContent
        );
    }
?>
```